Handmade number sequence puzzle: 14, 8, 98, 86, 58, ?, 34, 15,?
Hello ladies and gentlemen, I have crafted my own number sequence puzzle.
14, 8, 98, 86, 58, ?, 34, 15, ?
Hint:

Something in between... primes.. fibonacci...

